# R's `statsr rep_sample_n` - "sample with replacement" ... but when does "replacement" happen?

Tags: r

R package `statsr` provides function [`rep_sample_n`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/statsr/versions/0.1-0/topics/rep_sample_n) which is described as:

> `rep_sample_n(tbl, size, replace = FALSE, reps = 1)`
>
> Value: A `tbl_df` that aggregates all created samples, with the
>   addition of a `replicate` column that the `tbl_df` is also grouped by

So you can write things like

```
> trial <- rep_sample_n(cars, size = 5, reps = 15, replace = TRUE) 
> show(trial)

# A tibble: 75 x 3
# Groups:   replicate [15]
   replicate speed  dist
 *     <int> <dbl> <dbl>
 1         1    20    56
 2         1    11    17
 3         1    19    36
 4         1    15    20
 5         1    12    20
 6         2    24   120
 7         2    14    36
 8         2    20    48
 9         2    23    54
10         2    16    40
# … with 65 more rows
```

But how does the `replace` work?

> `replace`: Sample with or without replacement?

When does `rep_sample_n` "replace" the observations to be sampled back into the sampling bag? Immediately after an observation has been pulled out at random, or only after it has pulled out `size` observations?

Comment: I think every `replace` argument in R works the same way. `base::sample` or `dplyr::sample_n`, you take `size` samples out of total observation always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easy to test empirically:

```r
library(statsr)

df <- data.frame(ID = letters[1:3], Value = 1:3)

rep_sample_n(df, size = 4, reps = 3, replace = TRUE) 
#> # A tibble: 12 x 3
#> # Groups:   replicate [3]
#>    replicate ID    Value
#>  *     <int> <fct> <int>
#>  1         1 a         1
#>  2         1 b         2
#>  3         1 a         1
#>  4         1 c         3
#>  5         2 a         1
#>  6         2 a         1
#>  7         2 a         1
#>  8         2 c         3
#>  9         3 a         1
#> 10         3 a         1
#> 11         3 b         2
#> 12         3 a         1
```

You can see that the answer to your question is "it is replaced immediately".

<sup>Created on 2020-02-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>